# scanning java classpath in the maven plugin

Tags: java, reflection, maven-2, classpath, maven-plugin

What I'm trying to do is to write some Maven plugin which scans application classes looking for implementation of a particular interface (it might be classes with some annotation as well) and basis on the result generating some code. I've successfully implemented plugin running in the generate-sources phase and writing source code to the generated-sources directory.

The problem is with scanning classpath for the particular interface implementations/classes with some annotation.
I am using the [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library to scan classes in the following way:

```
private Set<Class< ? extends MyInterface >> scan(final String packageName) {
  final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName);  
  return reflections.getSubTypesOf(MyInterface.class);
}
```

Unfortunately, this method returns empty set. When I print my classpath in the class extending `org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo` (the same within which I'm using [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/)) I get the following result:

> /home/pd5108/apache-maven-2.2.1/boot/classworlds-1.1.jar

The classes I want to find using Reflections exists in dependend JARs as well as in the module within which plugin is configured. Looking at the classpath printed out it seems that at this point (generate-sources phase) dependencies defined in maven all not available on classpath yet - probably they are added in the next phases. Is that true? Is there any other approach I can use?

Here is the way how classpath is printed out:

```
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)sysClassLoader).getURLs();

for(int i=0; i< urls.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(urls[i].getFile());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Required MOJO class fields:

```
    /**
    * The project currently being built.
    *
    * @parameter expression="${project}"
    * @readonly
    * @required
    */
    private MavenProject project;

    /** @parameter expression="${localRepository}" */
    protected ArtifactRepository m_localRepository;

    /**@parameter default-value="${localRepository}" */
    private org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository
        localRepository;

    /** @parameter default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}" */
    private java.util.List remoteRepositories;

    /** @component */
    private org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.ArtifactFactory artifactFactory;

    /** @component */
    private org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver resolver;
```

Resolution of all dependencies JARs:

```
 final List<Dependency> dependencies = project.getDependencies();

    for (Dependency d : dependencies) {

        final Artifact artifact =
            artifactFactory.createArtifactWithClassifier(d.getGroupId(),
                d.getArtifactId(), d.getVersion(), d.getType(),
                d.getClassifier());

        try {
            resolver.resolve(artifact, remoteRepositories,
                    localRepository );
        } catch (ArtifactResolutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ArtifactNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File artifactFile = artifact.getFile();
        System.out.println(artifactFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

And now we need to scan these JARs using reflection API looking for the appropriate classes.
At this point I think that there's no other way, since I work in `generate-sources` phase and artifact values for the next phases are not computed yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are artifact dependencies defined in `<dependencies>` section and plugin dependencies defined under `<plugin><dependencies>`.

Plugin dependencies are added to the classpath while I am not sure about the artifact dependencies. Did you try to add your plugin dependencies under the `<plugin><dependencies>`?

Comment: According to your advice, I've added a 'plugin dependency' and now it's not visible under the classpath printed out (strange), but Reflections library detects classes implementing MyInterface properly! Is there any way I can include artifact dependencies in plugin dependencies? I'd love to avoid copy-pasting of the whole section :/

Comment: @PiotrekDe Maybe you can create a jar project with all the necessary dependencies which you would use as dependency for both the POM and the plugin. I am not sure it is worth the pain though...

Answer (score -2):

Might be quicker/safer/easier to just have the plugin config list the classes you want to generate code based on.  Then you just add it to the pom and you're done.  No reflection needed, and it'd certainly speed up the running of the plugin.

Comment: It's the option I consider as a last resort... Since I have a lot of classes implementing this interface and all of them are considered in the code generation I'd like to avoid typing all of them 'statically'. Also, these classes are frequently added/removed.

Comment: You could always have a shell script that did something like grep all java files for "implements X" and then parsed the class names out and build up a property file of them.  Then have your plugin use that property file to know what classes to generate extra code for as well.  If you're not on unix, you could emulate the grep in java I suppose, but it'd be much slower.